# Return groupings where at least one row per group satisfies a condition SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table (let's call it `TableA`) with multiple columns, `Id` being the unique id one.

I'm only interested in three: `A` (int), `B` (int), `C` (varchar).

Initially I want to pick up the rows which share the same `A` and `B` and return at least 2 rows.

```
; WITH CTE AS (
    SELECT      tbl.A, tbl.B
    FROM        [dbo].[TableA] tbl
    /* WHERE irrelevant filter here */
    GROUP BY    tbl.A, tbl.B
    HAVING      COUNT(1) > 1
)
```

From this point on, I want to return the groupings identified in this CTE where AT LEAST one row in each grouping has it's `C` column set to `'ThisValue'`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use sum with case to count the records that have 'ThisValue'

```
; WITH CTE AS (
    SELECT      tbl.A, tbl.B
    FROM        [dbo].[TableA] tbl
    /* WHERE irrelevant filter here */
    GROUP BY    tbl.A, tbl.B
    HAVING      COUNT(1) > 1 and sum(case tbl.C when 'ThisValue' then 1 else 0 end)>0
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can, for example, use EXISTS operator.

```
; WITH CTE AS (
    SELECT      tbl.A, tbl.B
    FROM        [dbo].[TableA] tbl
    /* WHERE irrelevant filter here */
    GROUP BY    tbl.A, tbl.B
    HAVING      COUNT(1) > 1
)
SELECT * FROM CTE
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM [dbo].[TableA] tc 
WHERE tc.A=CTE.A AND tc.B=CTE.B AND tc.C='ThisValue');
```